# Removing unneeded graphical drivers?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, uninstall

I have an Intel GMA 4500M graphic card. In synaptic package manager I found out that there are a bunch of installed packages for nvidia and ATI. I was wondering if I can remove these packages since I have an Intel graphics card. Any recommendations for uninstalling unneeded packages?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have an `Intel 910GL Integrated Graphics Controller` and I purged all the packages not connected with my graphics card, so now I have

```
$ dpkg -l | grep xorg
ii  xserver-xorg                         1:7.5+6ubuntu3                                    the X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                    2:1.9.0-0ubuntu7.3                                Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev             1:2.3.2-6ubuntu3.1                                X.Org X server -- evdev input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-mouse             1:1.5.0-2build1                                   X.Org X server -- mouse input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev             1:0.4.2-2ubuntu2                                  X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel             2:2.12.0-1ubuntu5.1                               X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa              1:2.3.0-3build1                                   X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
```

This setup works for me, but I cannot guarantee it will work for everybody... ;) Make a note of all packages you uninstall, and if you bump into problems, boot into the recovery mode and install them back, for instance

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
```

One more note: do not clean the `dpkg` cache (`sudo apt-get clean`), because when you uninstall a package, and then you want to install it back, the package will be in the cache and `apt-get` will not have to download it again (this could be a problem when in the recovery mode).

Another note: save your original `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file, and after you've uninstalled the drivers and all seems OK, check the new `Xorg.0.log` for errors. This way you will be able to see if Xorg is happy with the new setup.

Comment: Thx for tip. I deleted all nvidia and ati packages. Well, i have deleted cache but everything works fine for now :)